# How to edit expandable objects in root row in PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, propertygrid, propertydescriptor

Need help with PropertyGrid.

I have List of CustomClass to display it in PropertyGrid Control.
I want to modify CustomClass instance's properties right in the propertygrid. (Condition is that there shouldn't be editors).
Using ExpandableObjectConverters and PropertyDescriptors as shown in related article, i can modify every CustomClass instances in List by expanding it to properties. But my goal is to modify CustomClass properties in it's row without expanding. (Example behaviour you can find for SomeControl Size property in VS Control Properties View)

How can i edit expandable objects in root row?

[image: image from article]

Detail question for this picture: How to change Max Headroom from it's "Sales, Manager" to "Sales, Director" without expanding.
(my problem that this row is readonly field)

Related article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert?msg=4745311#xx4745311xx 
I've posted a question there too (no answer yet).

I can generate some basic code sample if it's too complicated.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You have to create custom `ExpandableObjectConverter` and override the `CanConvertFrom` and `ConvertFrom` method to enable editing of `Max HeadRoom` object's string representation.

Check the `SpellingOptionsConverter` in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) example.

Comment: thank you @Junaith.
there is also a reference to this [topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx#vsnetpropbrow_topic03).
I'm trying now to use it in my concrete example..

Comment: @Pavel - Glad to help. The topic you referred also uses the same logic. If the issue is resolved could you accept it as answer.